# How to reference Docker container in ConnectionString

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have 2 docker images, one for my backend and one for a mock database. I want to spin up these two images separately and link the backend to the database. To do this I have a connection string in my backend like so `Data Source=192.168.99.100;Catalog=DB name;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";` where `192.168.99.100` is the IP of my default Docker machine where the database container is running. So on my Windows machine this works perfectly and the backend container can communicate with the database which is running on another container. However, when some of my colleagues who use Mac and Linux use the same images they can't get the link to work because they obviously don't have the same IP for their Docker machine.

Is there any way to reference the database in the connection string so that it is the same no matter where it is running? For example use the name of the database container, instead of the IP or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this using plain docker. Basically you just need to create a bridge network, and then attach both containers to it.

Eg:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge mynetwork
docker run --network=mynetwork --name mydb mydb:latest
docker run --network=mynetwork --name myapp myapp:latest
```

Then inside the `myapp` container you can reference the database container using the hostname `mydb` (same as with docker-compose). You can still expose ports in the `myapp` container to your host using `-p 3000:3000`, etc

Further reading: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `docker-compose` services to achieve what you are looking for. Here is a simplified example docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  db:
    container_name: mock_db
    restart: "no"
    build: ./mock_db
    expose:
      - 5432 (or whatever your port is)
    env_file: .env
    command: your-command

  server:
    container_name: my_server
    build: ./server
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    command: your-command
```

You can then reference the service name (in this case `db`) as the ip/url part of your connection string.

You can read more about `docker-compose` configuration options [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)